# Restart Generator that Consumes a Refillable Iterator

Tags: python, generator

I have a problem using a generator that is using a refillable iterator.

Here is my simple generator:

```
def hi(iterable):
  for val in iterable:
    yield val
```

The iterable that I pass into the hi generator is the Reservoir class from the [functional_pipes repo](https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/functional_pipes/blob/master/functional_pipes/pipe.py) that can be refilled after it has exhausted its elements.

I would like to consume the hi generator until StopIteration is raised and then refill the iterable and then consume it again like

```
refillable = Reservoir((1, 2, 3, 4))
hi_iter = hi(refillable)

print(tuple(hi_iter))

refillable((5, 6, 7, 8))
print(tuple(hi_iter))
```

but this prints

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
()
```

The second tuple should also be (5, 6, 7, 8).

The only solution that I have found for this is wrapping the hi generator with a class

```
def super_gener(function):
  class wrapper_class:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
      self.iterable = iterable
      self.zipped = None

    def __iter__(self):
      return self

    def __next__(self):
      try:
        return next(self.zipped)

      except TypeError:
        self.zipped = function(self.iterable)
        return next(self)

      except StopIteration as err:
        self.zipped = None
        raise err

  return wrapper_class

hi_iter = super_gener(hi)(refillable)

print(tuple(hi_iter))
refillable(data)
print(tuple(hi_iter))
```

This solution seems a bit excessive and I'm looking for a simpler solution. Thanks for your help.

In response to Ptank:
I cannot save the iterable to a tuple because the iterable is not always yielding the same items and the items are not known before refillable is filled the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the only solution might be to create a refillable generator wrapper class. EDIT: Original untested code wasn't working. I have now refactored the idea below and tested it.

This object will raise `StopIteration` ONCE, after which it will restart. It is intended to be used with the `Resettable` decorator, which adds a `_func` attribute to the class. It should have all the same functionality of the original generator.

```
class ResettableGenerator():
    '''Generator wrapper that is resettable.'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.start()
    def __next__(self):
        n = self.send(None)
        return n
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._gen
    def start(self):
        self._gen = self._func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    def send(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            n = self._gen.send(*args, **kwargs)
            return n
        except StopIteration:
            self.start()
            raise
    def throw(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._gen.throw(*args, **kwargs)
    def close(self):
        self._gen.close()
```

Here is the decorator:

```
def Resettable(some_func):
    cls = type(some_func.__name__, (ResettableGenerator,), {})
    cls._func = staticmethod(some_func)
    return cls
```

Use it like this:

```
@Resettable
def f():
    yield 1
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
>>> g=f()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __next__
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in send
StopIteration
>>> next(g)
1 #  generator has restarted itself
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I like how this has the decorator and can take any generator.

Comment: Coming back to this a couple years later after having forgot about it: I'd implement slightly differently today, I think. But I'd say creating a wrapper class and a decorator using it is probably still the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to update `hi` to be a generator factory and call it each time you want to use it. This is cleaner than your current solution, but may not work in your case for other reasons.

```
def hi(iterable):
    def wrapper():
        for val in iterable:
            yield val
    return wrapper
```

With similar usage as you're currently using:

```
refillable = Reservoir((1, 2, 3, 4))
hi_iter = hi(refillable)
print(tuple(hi_iter())) # (1, 2, 3, 4)

refillable((5, 6, 7, 8))
print(tuple(hi_iter())) # (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

If you want to keep the exact same syntax as your original example, you could create a similarly thin class.

```
class hi:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.__iter__ = lambda: iterable
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jared. Unfortunately, I cannot in most cased redefine the generator that I'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar situation of yours. The difference is that in my case, the generator itself handles refilling the iterator.

```
def getRandomWordGenerator():
   words = RandomWords().get_random_words()
   for w in words:
       yield w
   for w in getRandomWordGenerator():
       yield w
```

This will generate words infinitely. words variable is a list of words, when it is exhausted, the function calls itself to generate another list and keeps yielding words. Hope this helps you and newcomers.

To loop on it, you could do the following:

```
r = getRandomWordGenerator()
for i in r:
   pass
```

OR define a function that will return you the value, abstract away the generator, like so

```
r = getRandomWordGenerator()
def getRandomWord():
    return next(r)
```

Notice how we are defining the generator in the outer scope of the function.

Or even better you could do the following

```
def getRandomWord():

    def getRandomWordGenerator():
        words = RandomWords().get_random_words()
        for w in words:
            yield w
        for w in getRandomWordGenerator():
            yield w
    r = getRandomWordGenerator()
    def f():
        return next(r)
    return f

getRandomWord = getRandomWord()
```

Much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

That because generator aren't Tuple, generator yielded is memoryless and readable only one time.

Just use a tuple

```
def hi(iterable):
    return tuple(iterable)
```

Comment: I cannot save the iterable to a tuple because the iterable is not always yielding the same items and the items are not known before refillable is filled the second time.